Azure key vault certificate throws bad parameter error
When I upload the certificate as this:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{my certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
{my key}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I am getting the error:
The type of the private key of the X.509 certificate content is not supported. Supported key types are: [ec, ec-hsm, rsa, rsa-hsm].

Can you tell me why I am not able to upload the certificate?
https://docs.solarisgroup.co.uk/guides/encryption-examples/#Java
i am referring the above link and trying to use the private/public keys used in this example.

How are you generating the certificate?

https://docs.solarisgroup.co.uk/guides/encryption-examples/#Java
i am referring the above link and trying to use the private/public keys used in this example. i have created pem file with both keys. then tried uploading it  to my azure keyvault using keyvault->certificate->import.

So you are just copying the private and public key from the reference and created a pem cert directly and try to upload? Is this right?

yes. is it possible to use those keys?

Initially I used the same public and private key from the blog and created a .pem file. When tried to upload I got the same error:

The error "The type of the private key of the X.509 certificate content is not supported. Supported key types are: [ec, ec-hsm, rsa, rsa-hsm]." usually occurs if there is an issue with private key being used or formatted when you're attempting to upload the certificate to Azure Key Vault.

Azure Key Vault supports the following private key types   RSA , RSA-HSM AND  EC , EC-HSM
The private key you're using seems to be in PKCS#1 format, which is the older format for RSA keys.

Hence to resolve the error and upload the cert to Azure key vault check the below:
# 1. Generate RSA private key
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out rsa_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

# 2. Generate CSR (Certificate Signing Request)
openssl req -new -key rsa_key.pem -out csr.pem

# 3. Generate self-signed certificate
openssl x509 -req -in csr.pem -signkey rsa_key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3650

# 4. Combine the private key and certificate into a single file
copy cert.pem + rsa_key.pem combinedruk.pem


Edit the file and remove the ? from the end of the file and save:

Now I am able to upload the .pem file successfully:



i am able to upload certificate with newly generated keys. but thats not my requirement.

Afaik you cannot use the keys mentioned in the doc

newly generated keys does not work for sign/verrify functions used in that example. it throws "invalidkeyspecexception" when i use "keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes));"..

public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKeyString) throws Exception {
String publicKeyPEM = publicKeyString
.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
.replaceAll("\r\n", "")
.replaceAll("\n", "");
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes));
}


To resolve the InvalidKeySpecException, ensure that you're correctly handling the PEM public key, decoding it correctly, and making sure the public and private keys match. This should allow you to perform signing and verification functions without errors.

in the previous comment you were mentioned that your were also getting an error while using the keys from the blog. if it is working now how did you resolve it? can you please share the steps and file which were used to upload in keyvault?

Yes initially I got the error, you check my above answer where I used openssl and generated a cert and uploaded as described

Are you copying the public key? Please verify
